# Oracle procedure not returning values into multiple OUT parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am calling a SP from another SP. I have a following 2 stored procedure I need to get both results into OUT parameter and I call this from Server side (dot Net). But It doesn't work . I am getting only `TABLE_LIST` results always. It doesn't return `counter` values ( logically 0 or 1 from the below statement) to OUT parameter. I am sharing part of my SP which is a pert of package.

```
PROCEDURE  SP_USERS
(
 
      P_USER_ID        INTEGER,
      P_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      P_CUR_LIST OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
 )
AS
 counter INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
     IF counter = 0 THEN
       OPEN P_CUR_LIST for select 0 as "success" from dual;
     ELSE
        OPEN P_CUR_LIST for select 1 as "success" from dual;
     END IF;   
     
     BEGIN
         SY_PROCEDURES.SP_GET_GRD(P_USER_ID,P_CUR); --calling another procedure
    END;
END SP_USERS;




PROCEDURE SP_GET_GRD(
  P_USER_ID INTEGER,
      P_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  AS
  BEGIN

    OPEN P_CUR FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE_LIST;
  END SP_GET_GRD;
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid as it has too many `END` statements.

Comment: I editted OP. .

Comment: Your code [does what you expect](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7763bfb1c703cd6b1e7743d99e24f9c) - both cursors have data. Given the stray `END;` you had to start with, I suspect that counter check/cursor open is inside some other logic you haven't shown, and you just aren't reaching it.

Comment: Your code works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b7717c358b2ddf656e45ea2a355503df).

Comment: @MT0 the code works. I found where the problem is... Thank you for your quick help;